# How to use Larvel Model eloquent with Join query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

What I want is, I have one more table "ratings" in which I store tutor_is and some rating of tutor. I want to get all ratings of each tutor and their average ratings by some join query

```
    $tutors=TutorTimeSlot::
                join('centers','centers.id', '=', 'tutor_time_slots.center_id')
                ->join('tutors', function ($join) use ($location_id) {
                    $join->on('tutors.id', '=', 'tutor_time_slots.tutor_id')
                    ->where('tutors.location_id',$location_id);
                })
                ->select('tutors.*','centers.id as center_id','centers.centername','centers.centerlocation','centers.lat','centers.lng')
                ->distinct()
                ->paginate(4);
return response()->json($tutors);
```

Comment: Why don't u use relationship?

Comment: I have no issue with relations but, i am saving tutor_id 's and center_id's in separate table on which i can't define any relation.

Comment: above code is working fine but i want data form "rating" table also.

Comment: are u making many to many relationship, if making then you can use relationship.

Comment: no sir, in ratings table i save some details of tutor, but here i can't use any relation between tutors and ratings table because i am querying on the basis of TutorTimeSlot model which is totally complete model and save only ids

Comment: is there any way to define between "tutors" table and "ratings" table

Comment: What are you going to show betwwn these two tables?

Comment: i want this output SELECT tutor_id,COUNT(tutor_id) as totalCount,round(AVG(rating),1)  as avgRatings FROM tutor_ratings GROUP By tutor_id

Comment: It's mean a relationship already exists b/w tutors and rating table. A tutor has many ratings?

Comment: yes but i am confused how to use that relation in above code

Comment: Here you can add you query: ->select('tutors.*','centers.id as center_id','centers.centername','centers.centerlocation','centers.lat','centers.lng')

Comment: that is already there but i need data from ratings table also

Comment: that's thing i am asking that you can put query in your existing query

Comment: but what about the relation b/w tutors and tutor_ratings

Comment: if i write select query there it is giving error like column not found in tutor_time_slots table

Comment: You can make the relation as you are making relationship b/w centers and tutor time slot table